# Extremal of the variational problem $J[y] = \int_{0}^1 (y'(x))^2 dx$ with the conditions $y(0)=0$, $y(1) = 1$ and $\int_{0}^1 y(x)dx =0$

Tags: functional-equations, calculus-of-variations, variational-analysis

I want to solve the variational problem $$ J[y] = \int_{0}^1 (y'(x))^2 dx $$ with the conditions $y(0)=0, y(1)=1$ and $\int_{0}^{1}y(x)dx = 0$.

Using Euler's condition (for an extremal):
$$ \frac{\partial F}{\partial y}- \frac{\partial^2 F}{ \partial x \partial  y'}- \frac{\partial ^2 F}{\partial y \partial y'} -y'' \frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y'^2} =0. $$

This will give: $ y'' \frac{\partial ^2 F}{\partial y}=0 $

If $y''=0$ then the solution is of the form $Ax+B$, which can not be the case here. After this point I am unable to solve the problem.

Can you please help me understand what am I doing wrong. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Which Euler's condition are you referring to? The Euler-Lagrange equation for this functional?

Comment: What do you mean by "Using Euler's condition we see ..."?  There are constraints on $y$...

Comment: @TeresaLisbon I have added more details to the question. Please have a look and guide me!

Comment: @user10354138 I have added more details to the question.

Comment: Will take a look , thanks

Comment: You cannot do this because it is a constrained problem.  You have instead searched for the extrema in the unconstrained domain (i.e., without any regards to $\int_0^1 y(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=0$).  (Also, I think you should have a $y'$ in front of $\frac{\partial^2 F}{\partial y\partial y'}$.)

Comment: @user10354138 I am preparing for objective questions for an entrance exam and I don't have the proper resources to learn the subject. Can you please suggest me some books or something with less theory and more examples to get a good grasp on the subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the lagrangian

$$
\int_0^1(\dot y)^2dt +\lambda\int_0^1 y dt
$$

then from Euler-Lagrange

$$
2\ddot y -\lambda = 0
$$

and solving with boundary conditions

$$
y = \frac 14(4t-\lambda t+\lambda t^2)
$$

The solution should satisfy the restriction so

$$
\int_0^1 ydt = \frac 12-\frac{\lambda}{24}=0\Rightarrow \lambda = 12
$$

and the solution is

$$
y = 3t^2-2 t
$$

Comment: The answer is $3x^2 - 2x$. Note that the integral will not be zero in this case.

Comment: You are right. The restriction defines the $\lambda$ value.

Comment: I have a naive question. How and when do we use the Lagrangian? I have no idea about this method. Please care to explain. Also using the Rayleigh ritz method this solution is obtained.

Comment: The Lagrange multipliers are used to integrate the restrictions into the lagrangian. The present case is very simple because we are handling an equality condition. You can see this in Gelfand & Fomin Calculus of Variations under the title Variational problems with subsidiary conditions.

Comment: Here http://users.uoa.gr/~pjioannou/mech2/READING/Gelfand_Fomin_Calculus_of_Variations.pdf